# Remove a string from the column when it meets the condition

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, string, dataframe

I would like to remove the string from a string column when it contains a lower letter (the string column may be NaN or include multiple string in one row)

| Column1 | Column2 | Column3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| NaN | NaN | NaN |
| BCDE8ENGUGUETNJN | NaN | NaN |
| vk4JGFIEh5 | NaN | NaN |
| t7chJGWYEj | BCSTACK | BCTENSORFLOW |
| 5hNIE7EEP | OVERFLOW | NaN |

The original df is look like the above

I have tried the "str.contains" function to locate and replace it when it contains lowerletter

Since str function could not be used for NaN value, I replaced the NaN value with string 'nan' first,

then aimed to replace all the lower letter with regex. Since 'nan' is also a lower letter, it should be replaced as well

> ```
> df['Column1'].fillna('nan',inplace=True)
> df['Column2'].fillna('nan',inplace=True)
> df['Column3'].fillna('nan',inplace=True)
>
> lowerletterpattern = r'[a-z]*'
>
> mask1 = df['Column1'].str.contains(lowerletterpattern)
> df.loc[mask1,'Column1'] = np.nan
>
> mask2 = df['Column2'].str.contains(lowerletterpattern)
> df.loc[mask2,'Column2'] = np.nan
>
> mask3 = df['Column3'].str.contains(lowerletterpattern)
> df.loc[mask3,'Column3'] = np.nan
> ```

but the df returned with all NaN value

Below is the expected result:

| Column1 | Column2 | Column3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| NaN | NaN | NaN |
| BCDE8ENGUGUETNJN | NaN | NaN |
| NaN | NaN | NaN |
| NaN | BCSTACK | BCTENSORFLOW |
| NaN | OVERFLOW | NaN |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option, check for `[a-z]` with [`str.contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) and [`mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html):

```
out = df.mask(df.apply(lambda s: s.str.contains('[a-z]').fillna(True)))
```

Or, with [`replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html):

```
out = df.replace('.*[a-z].*', float('nan'), regex=True)
```

Output:

```
            Column1   Column2       Column3
0               NaN       NaN           NaN
1  BCDE8ENGUGUETNJN       NaN           NaN
2               NaN       NaN           NaN
3               NaN   BCSTACK  BCTENSORFLOW
4               NaN  OVERFLOW           NaN
```

Comment: thank you so much the first option works!!! May I know why it also works with NaN value and do not need to fillna before using the lambda function?

Comment: In addition, may I know is it possible to detect if the columns contain similar String?

E.g. If Column 1 row 3 is "STACK" instead of "NaN"; and Column 1 row 4 is "BCOVERFLOW" instead of NaN"

Is it possible to detect it and remove "STACK" and "OVERFLOW" in that datapoint? Just keeping "BCSTACK", "BCTENSORFLOW" inw row 3 and "BCOVERFLOW" in row 4

Comment: @ProgramNewHand well you can do this kind of things but you'd have to provide a detailed logic. As this is not directly related to your current logic, can you please open a new question with all details?

Comment: sure! thank you so much for helping with the first question, it has been annoying me for about a week TAT!

Answer (score 1):

Another solution, using [`Series.where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html#pandas-series-where):

```py
df = df.apply(
    lambda row: row.where(~row.str.contains(r"[a-z]").astype(bool)),
    axis=1,
)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
            Column1   Column2       Column3
0               NaN       NaN           NaN
1  BCDE8ENGUGUETNJN       NaN           NaN
2               NaN       NaN           NaN
3               NaN   BCSTACK  BCTENSORFLOW
4               NaN  OVERFLOW           NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

You could avoid regex with `str.isupper`:

```
df = df.applymap(lambda x: x if type(x) == str and x.isupper() else np.NaN)
```

Comment: is it possible to amend the condition to upper-case and also numbers? As it may contains upper case and numbers as well, just want to remove string with lower case only, but thanks for your advise!

Comment: `x.isupper()` considers numbers to be uppercase too; it's equivalent to `x == x.upper()`.